# jQuery: color change doesn't work with Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

could you explain me why the following code doesn't work in Chrome and Safari, but only in Firefox ?

```
if ($(this).css("color") == "Fuchsia"){ $(this).css("color","#000000"); }
```

This is the link:

http://www.sanstitre.ch/drupal/portfolio?tid[0]=38

If you scroll down and up you'll see "Eternal Tour" becoming purple and black again, because it is not anymore selected. (with FIrefox)

With Chrome and Safari it remains black.

Comment: Try to spell it lowercase: fuchsia.

Comment: I think it has to do with the scrolling. Try to change the color on an other event...

Comment: @powtac post your answer below, we can upvote it then. (plus author can accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to spell it lowercase: fuchsia.

Answer (score 0):

I would trace what returns `$(this).color()` and see, but I would say that the main problem is, that chrome/safari both return `hex code`, so comparing against `string` doesn't work.

try to compare it against `#FF00FF`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($(*).css("color") == "fuchsia"){ $(this).css("color","#000000"); }
```

Comment: I'd avoid this. Not a good idea to loop through every element on the page

Answer (score 0):

```
    function toggleNotesStyle(obj) {

    var currentColor = rgb2hex(jQuery(obj).css('color'));

    if (currentColor == '#000000') {  // if black, change to red
        jQuery(obj).css('color', '#ff0000');
    }
    else {  // if a different color (red in our case), change to black
        jQuery(obj).css('color', '#000000');
    }
}

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    if (/^#[0-9a-f]{3}([0-9a-f]{3})?$/i.test(rgb)) {
        // matches on IE hex color (ie: #000000)  .. and no pun intended for "ie"
        return rgb;
    }
    // changes "rgb(#,#,#)' to hex for Mozilla, Chrome and Safari
        rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    // found this on another site, but don't know why it's different
    //rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
    return "#" +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

var timer;
toggleTimer();

function toggleTimer()
{
    if (document.getElementById("<%=fullDataEntryNotes.ClientID%>")) {
        var fullDataEntryNotes = document.getElementById("<%=fullDataEntryNotes.ClientID %>");
        toggleNotesStyle(fullDataEntryNotes);
    }

    timer = window.setTimeout('toggleTimer()', 750);
}
```

The HTML code breaks my post, so I'll explain what's in the HTML here.  Make a div tag, and put text inside of it.  Then style your div tag so it has a style.color attribute of #000000 (black) initially.  Then every 750 milliseconds, it'll toggle from black to red to black to red, etc..